# How we do double integration with variable bornes?

Tags: probability

If I apply the change of variable method to calculate a double integral, and I pose ( x = u ) and ( y = v-u ), with ( x ) and ( y ) being strictly positive, then we will find that the domain is ( 0 < u < v ). However, I encounter a problem regarding the domain of ( v ). Is it ( v > 0 ) or ( v > u )? Because if I choose the latter, I will obtain a result related to ( u ). As far as I know, we must obtain a fixed integral with variable limits. So, what is the correct choice and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable of integration does not "exist" outside of the integral. When you perform a change of variables in a double integral, you set the bounds of integration so that the overall region of integration is equivalent to the original integral.

For example, you can treat the integral $\int_A F(x, y)\ dx\ dy$ over the area $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ as a double integral $\int_{A_y} \left(\int_{A_x(y)} F(x, y)\ dx\right)\ dy$ where the inner integral, with respect to $x$, happens over a range of $x$ values that depend on $y$. Once you do that inner integral, what you have left is a function of $y$, i.e. $G(y) = \int_{A_x(y)} F(x, y)\ dx$ and then the outer integral becomes $\int_{A_y} G(y)\ dy$, and the final result doesn't depend on either variable.

When you transform $(x, y) \rightarrow (u, v)$, you will:

1. Change the function being integrated, i.e. $\tilde{F}(u, v) = F(x(u, v), y(u, v))$.
2. Introduce the Jacobian to change the variables, i.e. you'll make the substitution $dx\ dy = \left|\frac{d(u, v)}{d(x, y)}\right|\ du\ dv$.
3. Change the region of integration, i.e. you'll map $A$ to $\tilde{A}$ in the $(u, v)$ plane.

With the region of integration, if you break up the new integral into a double integral, then you need to map the values in such a way that the dependence on a variable stays within its integral.

So, for example, if the original $A$ is the square $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ and you want to make the substitution $x = u, y = v - u$, then the new region is $\tilde{A} = \{(u, v) : u \in [0, 1], v \in [u, u + 1]\}$ which is a parallelogram. If you want to integrate with respect to $v$ first then you can write the integral as

$$\int_0^1 \int_u^{u+1} G(u, v)\ dv\ du$$

but if you want to integrate $u$ out first then you'll need to figure out the equivalent bounds - it will be something like

$$\int_0^2 \int_{\max(0, v - 1)}^{\min(1, v + 1)} G(u, v)\ du\ dv$$

Either way, after you evaluate the inner integral - including the bounds - you'll get something that only depends on the variable of the outer integral.